# Relationship between mode and band

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, lattice-model

I'm learning solid state physics. I'm very confused about the terms "band" and "mode".

There are acoustic mode and optics mode. There is a gap at the Brillioun zone boundary. They describe the lattice.

There are conduction band and valence band. There is an energy gap between bands as well. They describe the electrons in lattice.

Both have reduced zone scheme and extended zone scheme. I know they describe different things but is there a relationship between mode and band in general? Any similarity?

Comment: Phonons have two different "modes" because the can vibrate in two different ways - at $k=0$ they look very different. Electronic band structures do not have "modes" per se, although there are potentially spin effects.